# WRL: how to subscribe to events *without* using lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++-cx

Subscribing to events in C++/CX goes something like this:

```
listener::ConnectionReceived +=
ref new TypedEventHandler<StreamSocketListener^, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^>(this, &MyClass::OnConnectionReceived);
```

All documentation I've found for how to subscribe to events in WRL shows examples using lambda expressions, like this:

```
auto connectionReceivedHandler = Callback<ITypedEventHandler<StreamSocketListener*, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs*>>
([&] (IStreamSocketListener* cbListener, IStreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs* args)
{
    this->doSomething(); 
});
hr = listener->add_ConnectionReceived(connectionReceivedHandler.Get(), &this->connectionReceivedToken);
```

But how can I subscribe to an event in WRL and provide a class method instead of a lambda? Something like this:

```
hr = listener->add_ConnectionReceived(&MyClass::OnConnectionReceived, &this->connectionReceivedToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WRL but since it supports C++11 lambdas I believe it should also support [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
auto callback = Callback<ITypedEventHandler<StreamSocketListener*,
                                       StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs*>>
  (std::bind(
    &MyClass::OnConnectionReceived,
    ptr_to_instance_of_MyClass,  // eg. this
    std::placeholders::_1,       // cbListener
    std::placeholders::_2        // args
  ));

hr = listener->add_ConnectionReceived(callback.Get(), &this->connectionReceivedToken);
```

Comment: I'm getting access violation errors when trying to access class members inside my callback, but that's a different problem for a separate post. This answers my question, thanks!

Comment: @Robert Segfault accessing class members likely means `ptr_to_instance_of_MyClass` is dangling. Did you have the same problem with lambdas? If so, check the lifetime of your `MyClass` instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of Callback that takes this + member function. here it is...

```
ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(_In_ TCallbackObject *object, _In_ HRESULT(TCallbackObject::* method)(TArgs...)) throw()
```

Comment: Pro tip: Prepend (each line of your) code with 4 spaces to format it properly as a code block.